# Google API costs

Tags: google-api, google-translate

where do I see daily costs in the Google API interface for Translate?  I can see how many requests sent but I can't see the actual cost breakdown.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Price Calculator here, to get the correct price on your quota!

[Google Cloud Price Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate API pricing can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing).

```
Prices per month

                    0-1.5 billion characters              1.5 billion+ 
Translation         $20 per 1,000,000  characters*         $15 per 1,000,000 characters* 
Language Detection  $20 per 1,000,000 characters*          $15 per 1,000,000 characters*
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 02 APR 2020

Effective 11/1/2019, up to $10 worth of free usage/month will be applied to Billed accounts using either the Basic or Advanced editions of the Cloud Translation API. The usage applies to NMT and PBMT text translation, and language detection calls, collectively.

More details can be found here https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing

Comment: why do I need to add a payment method when I'm going to use just the voucher?